# Replace strings contain whitespace using sed command shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I am trying to replace the strings in an xml file using the sed command. My script contains the following code.

```
SEARCH='key="identifierA" value ="000000 00:00:00"'
REPLACE='key="identifierA" value ="101617 00:00:00"'

TEST_DIR=home/test/
TEST_FILE="test.xml"

ChangeXml(){

ModifyValue $TEST_DIR $TEST_FILE $SEARCH $REPLACE

}

ModifyValue (){
cd $1
echo "Search : $3 Replace : $4 "
sed -i "s/$3/$4/g" $2
}

#Actions performed

ChangeXml
```

But this #3 in the echo returns **identifierA** and $4 returns **000000 00:00:00**. Its supposed to give the value assigned to those variables instead. Due to this replace is not working as expected. Tried to escape the space in between *key="identifierA" value ="000000 00:00:00"*. But not getting the results. I am very new to the shell scripting. Can anyone tell me the reason and correct me to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the variables if they can contain whitespace:

```
ModifyValue "$TEST_DIR" "$TEST_FILE" "$SEARCH" "$REPLACE"
```

Otherwise, $SEARCH is sent in pieces (split on whitespace) and populates more than one argument.

Comment: Hi, it worked perfectly. is there any better solution using the sed?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? It worked perfectly, how could it work even perfectlier?

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was the way I replace the strings.